# Can the NOT operator work on multiple conditions present in parenthesis?

Tags: mysql, sql, not-operator

I run following query in MySQL :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE NOT Country='Germany' AND NOT Country='USA';
```

It returned me exactly the correct expected result.

After that I run following query :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE NOT (Country='Germany' AND Country='USA');
```

This time it returned me **all the records** present in the table(result-set of the query `SELECT * FROM Customers;`)

I'm not understanding why the NOT operator is not working in second query with parenthesis?

You can go to this link and check :

```
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where_not_and
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got bitten by operator priority. Parentheses are your friend, you see.

```
WHERE NOT Country='Germany' AND NOT Country='USA';
```

actually means, since NOT has precedence over AND:

```
WHERE (NOT Country='Germany') AND (NOT Country='USA');
```

Since "NOT a=b" is "a!=b", this means:

```
WHERE Country!='Germany' AND Country!='USA';
```

which, as the others pointed out, looks muuuuch better like this:

```
WHERE Country NOT IN ('Germany', 'USA');
```

Now, next topic. This one:

```
WHERE NOT (Country='Germany' AND Country='USA');
```

Country can not be Germany and USA at the same time, so the stuff inside the () is always FALSE, so this equates to:

```
WHERE NOT (FALSE);
```

i.e.

```
WHERE TRUE;
```

ie, you get your whole table.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course it can.  But, by the rules of boolean logic, the correct formulation uses `OR`, not `AND`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE NOT (Country = 'Germany' OR Country = 'USA');
```

Your condition is:

```
WHERE NOT (Country = 'Germany' AND Country = 'USA');
```

Obviously, a single row cannot meet both conditions at the same time, because `Country` has only one value.  Hence, one every row, the `AND` evaluates to false, and `NOT` turns it into true -- so not filtering occurs.

The more typical way to write this is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Country NOT IN ('Germany', 'USA');
```

Comment: Then how the first query is my question is working fine and returning correct result-set with the operator 'AND'?

Comment: I think you meant "NOT IN" in the last line, instead of "NOT"

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a `OR` condition rather since the same column can't take multiple value at any point in time and thus your condition will bound to return `false`. Moreover, instead of using multiple stacked `OR` condition you should use `IN` operator like

```
WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'USA');
```

(OR)

```
WHERE Country NOT IN ('Germany', 'USA');
```

Your current condition will be evaluated as follows: `(Country='Germany' AND Country='USA')` will return `false` and `NOT false` will return `true`. Thus making your `WHERE` part `true` and returning all result

Comment: Then how the first query is my question is working fine and returning correct result-set with the operator 'AND'?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE NOT (Country='Germany' AND Country='USA');
```

What this is really saying is does this record not equal to both at the same time.  You couldn't have one row where you had the following as a positive:

```
(Country='Germany' AND Country='USA')
```

You would get the results you are looking for with the following:

```
Where Country not in ('Germany', 'USA')
```